# Get alias of unicode symbols

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, unicode, delphi-7

Are there any WinAPI to get the name of the Unicode character? At the moment I only know one way is to parse http://unicode.org/Public/6.1.0/ucd/NamesList.txt file.

Comment: Windows definitely is not up to Unicode 6.1.0. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far I know there is not a WinAPi function  to retrieve that information, but you can parse the  [`UnicodeData.txt`](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt) (from the unicode.org) file easily, here you have the description of that file [`Unicode Character Database`](http://unicode.org/reports/tr44/).

Comment: Or use the undocumented `GetUName` function from the same named `GetUName.dll` as my dependency walker bring me to. It is used e.g. by `Charmap` and since it has an export, it's not so risky to use it, +1ed anyway.

Comment: If you use the GeUName function all you can know for sure is that you'll get the same list of unicode codepoints that Windows already knows about. If you care about obscure or newly added points, you should go directly to whatever version of the Unicode.org data files you need.